# Select Query is very slow and sometime hangs my database

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help on suggestion on how I can make such a query faster

```
SELECT count(distinct tweet_id) count 
FROM tweets 
WHERE tweet_id NOT IN 
     (
      SELECT distinct in_reply_to_status_id 
      FROM tweets_response 
      WHERE created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)) 
       AND created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR
     )
```

I have place indexes on tweet_id and created_at but it's still slow

Comment: run your query in a console prefixed this way `\W;EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT count(distinct tweet_id) count FROM ..` and paste it's output here

Comment: distinct in the subquery is redundant

Comment: Make sure you have an index on in_reply_to_status_id too

Comment: Thanks guys, forgot to add an index on the in_reply_to_status_id. I agree, the distinct on the subquery is redundant. it now works fast like magic. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suspect the issue is indexes (and the comments above on doing an explain are 100% correct), but using a subselect is not necessary. Your query could be rewritten as:-

```
SELECT count(distinct tweet_id) `count` 
FROM tweets 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tweets_response 
ON tweets.tweet_id = tweets_response.in_reply_to_status_id AND tweets_response.created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
WHERE tweets_response.in_reply_to_status_id IS NULL
AND tweets.created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

Comment: Thanks, will check out this one too

Answer (score 0):

This should be better. 
Subselects tend to be very slow.

```
SELECT count(distinct tweet_id)
FROM tweets twt
LEFT OUTER JOIN tweets_response tr
    ON twt.tweet_id = tr.in_reply_to_status_id 
WHERE tr.in_reply_to_status_id IS NULL and (tr.created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)) 
   AND tr.created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```